# Akamai vs pagespeed module

Tags: cache, page-speed

We have akamai as CDN, we also have Apache before our website. We want to utilise the page speed module benefits. We are just worried about how page speed cache will affect our application where we also have akamai cache.

Is it any beneficial to use pagespeed cache along with akamai cache or just use other features in paespeed like collapse whitespace.